# How to solve 'Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetchAll'?

Tags: php

I followed a tutorial about taking students attendance. But, it doesn't give results that should be done. Instead, it gives me this:
`Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetchAll() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ah\includes\functions.php on line 62`

This is where the `fetchAll` is located:

```
function get_all_std($conn,$table,$limit){

        try {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM {$table} ORDER BY  std_roll_no LIMIT {$limit}";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare( $query );
                $stmt->execute();
                return $stmt->fetchAll();

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return "ERROR". $e->getMessage();
        }

      }
```

And this is where the `function` `get_all_std` :

```
<?php        
        $view = $db->get_all_std($conn,'student_table',10);
        foreach ($view as $post) {
        $std_id = $post['std_roll_no'];

      echo '<tr>';

        // echo '<td>'. $post['student_id'] . '</td>';          
        echo '<td>'. $post['student_name'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $post['dob'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $post['gender'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $post['email'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $post['phone'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $post['address'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $post['Session'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $post['Program'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $post['Semester'] . '</td>';

        echo '<td width=250>';
        echo "<div class='ui mini buttons'>";
        echo '<a class="ui mini positive button" href="student_update.php?std_roll_no='.$post['std_roll_no'].'"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>Update</a>';
        echo "<div class='or'></div>";    
        echo '<a class="ui mini red button" href="student.php?std_roll_no='.$post['std_roll_no'].'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"> </i>Delete</a>';
        echo "</div>";
        echo '</td>';    
       echo '</tr>';  
        }
       ?>
```

So I would like to know how to solve this, because I already researched in the internet but none can solve my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `fetch_all()`- `fetchAll()` is the PDO version of that function.

Comment: Nope, I still get the same results `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_all() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ah\includes\functions.php on line 62`

Comment: After having a closer look: `fetch_all()` is a method of the result object and not the statement itself.

Comment: okay, so do you have any suggestion instead of doing this way?

Answer (score 0):

It's okay. I already solved the problem. Instead from using the `code sample` that I given above.

I changed the code structure to:

```
 <?php        
        $count=1;
        $sel_query="Select * from student_table ORDER BY student_id;";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sel_query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

      echo '<tr>';

        echo '<td>'. $row['student_ID'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['school_ID'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['student_name'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['student_class'] . '</td>';

        echo '<td width=250>';
        echo "<div class='ui mini buttons'>";
        echo '<a class="ui mini positive button" href="student_update.php?student_ID='.$row['student_ID'].'"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>Update</a>';
        echo "<div class='or'></div>";    
        echo '<a class="ui mini red button" href="student.php?student_ID='.$row['student_ID'].'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"> </i>Delete</a>';
        echo "</div>";
        echo '</td>';    
       echo '</tr>';  
        }
       ?>
```

Which means I didn't use the `fetch_all` function. And I changed `$post` to `$row`.